# How can I get contact form added information on the control panel?

Tags: craft3, plugin-contactform

I'm using the contact form plugin to implement the contact form on the front, now I want to see all the contact information on the control panel, So how can I get that in the control panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Contact Form Extensions plugin in plugin store. It’s free to use.

Install it and then fill the setting form as you need it. After that settings completed you will see the new option “Form Submisson” in your side bar menu in control panel. You will get all filled contact form records in it from now on.